# Remove parent JPanel when JButton is clicked

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

I have a ArrayList of JPanel. And each items of this list has a JButton.
Now, when JButton is clicked I want to remove its' parent JPanel from the ArrayList. So how can I make the JButton remove its' parent from the ArrayList?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TestingArrayList extends JFrame {

JPanel grandPanel;  // a JPanel for all the panels
ArrayList<JPanel> panelParent = new ArrayList<>();  // JPanel ArrayList

public TestingArrayList() {
    super("Test");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    grandPanel = new JPanel();
    add(grandPanel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  // adding 10 JPanel into grandPanel
        panelParent.add(new JPanel());
        grandPanel.add(panelParent.get(i));

        // adding JButton in all panels
        JButton btnParent = new JButton("X");
        panelParent.get(i).add(btnParent);

        // add new task button action
        btnParent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(getParent());
                //What to do!!!
            }
        });
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1000, 100);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestingArrayList();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for this.When JButton is clicked I want to remove its' parent JPanel from the ArrayList. So how can I make the JButton remove its' parent from the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all you need right in your code. You just need a `final` reference to the JPanel of interest as this will allow you to use it within the anonymous inner ActionListener class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 

    // make it final so that it is accessible from inner anon class
    final JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    panelParent.add(myPanel);
    grandPanel.add(myPanel);

    JButton btnParent = new JButton("X");
    myPanel.add(btnParent);

    btnParent.addActionListener(event -> panelParent.remove(myPanel));
}
```

If you also want to remove it from the grandPanel, then you'll need more...

```
btnParent.addActionListener(event -> {
    panelParent.remove(myPanel);
    grandPanel.remove(myPanel);
    grandPanel.revalidate();
    grandPanel.repaint();
});
```

---

Note, that if you wanted to use Seymore's method of removing the JPanel, you first need to understand that the source object obtained by calling `getSource()` on the ActionEvent parameter is the object that the listener was added to -- here a `JButton` not a `JPanel`, and also the type of object returned is `Object`, and so no Swing component methods can be called on it without casting. And so you would need to wrap all in parenthesis in order to allow you to call methods of that type. For example:

```
parentPanel.remove((JPanel) ((JButton) event.getSource()).getParent());
```

or

```
parentPanel.remove((JPanel) ((JComponent) event.getSource()).getParent());
```

I find it easier to separate lines when code gets this convoluted:

```
// since a JButton extends from JComponent
JComponent source = (JComponent) event.getSource();
JPanel parent = (JPanel) source.getParent();
parentPanel.remove(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnParent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(getParent());
        panelParent.remove((JPanel)(event.getSource().getParent()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Seymore. But it's not working. getParent() method not working on this panel

Comment: @sapayth: he's casting the source to the wrong type, and not casting correctly with his parenthesis. Better to use the JPanel directly since it is easily accessible.

Comment: Seymore, that's still not correct. If you and @sapayth want to see the correct code on how to do this, please read the addition to my answer.

Comment: Edited because I forgot that the ArrayList holds JPanels only, not Containers

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.